# shapiro.test(..) cannot deal with more than 5000 data points

Tags: r, normal-distribution

In R, the `shapiro.test()` function cannot run if the sample size exceeds 5000.

```
shapiro.test(rnorm(10^4))
```

Why is it so ?
Can I overpass this limitation ?

Comment: You should read [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427692/perform-a-shapiro-wilk-normality-test/15427746#15427746)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a safety limitation. Please read this: [Perform a Shapiro-Wilk Normality Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427692/perform-a-shapiro-wilk-normality-test/15427746#15427746)

Other tests of normality do not have this limitation such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

```
ks.test(x=rnorm(10^4),y='pnorm',alternative='two.sided')
```

Comment: This works, but I watched someone doing a live code and they passed `shapiro.test()` with 9500 values, I do not know how they did it.