# test for normality

Tags: sql, plsql, statistics, poisson

What is the best way to fit test / test normality for each unique ilitm in the below dataset? Thanks

[image: dbtbl]

Answer (score 1):

As you know (visible in the edit history) Oracle provides the [Shapiro-Wilk](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/shapiro.test.html)
test of normality (I use a link to [[R]](https://www.r-project.org/), as you will find much more reference for this implementation).

The important thing to know is that the OUT parameter `sig` corresponds to what the statistics call the `p-value`.

Example

```
DECLARE
   sig     NUMBER;
   mean    NUMBER := 0;
   stdev   NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
   DBMS_STAT_FUNCS.normal_dist_fit (USER,
                                    'DIST',
                                    'DIST1',
                                    'SHAPIRO_WILKS',
                                    mean,
                                    stdev,
                                    sig);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (sig);
END;
/
```

you get the following output

```
W value : ,9997023261540432791888281834378157820514
,7136528702727722659486194469256296703232
```

For comparison the test in `r` with the same data

```
> shapiro.test(df$DIST1)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  df$DIST1
W = 0.9997, p-value = 0.7137
```

The rest is [statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/):)

My interpretation - this test is useful if you need to discard the most coarse deviations from the normal distribution

**If sig < .05 you may throw the data away as not normal distributed, but a high value of sig doesn't mean the opposite. You only know that you can't discard it as non-normal..**

Anyway a **plot of distribution** can provide better insight that a simple true/false test. Here is R a good resource as [well](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_%28ggplot2%29/).

Some other useful [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427692/perform-a-shapiro-wilk-normality-test) to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781798/seeing-if-data-is-normally-distributed-in-r/7788452#7788452).