# Which methods of normalization exist in R?

Tags: r, statistics, normalization

I'm working with data that is not normal distributed. I have applied the common methods: logs and square roots in order to transform the data and then treat it with an ARIMA model so I can make a forecast.

What I have tried is:

```
set.seed(123)
y<-rexp(200)

yl<-log(y+1)
shapiro.test(yl)

trans<-(y-mean(y))/sd(y)
shapiro.test(trans)
```

This methods are failing the test of normality, I would like to ask if there are another options to transform data into normal data in R.

Comment: This answer is an interesting read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781798/seeing-if-data-is-normally-distributed-in-r/7788452#7788452

Comment: Thanks, but that reading is related to normality tests. I can apply Jarque Bera test and the results will still have the same accordance.

Comment: Yes, the point is on the validity of normality tests and their assumptions. That is, you're testing for a "good" normalisation based on tests whose hypothesis are about rejecting the assumption of normality.

Comment: As well as @Arun's comments which are extremely relevant, you should be testing the **residuals** from your model, not the raw data.  You are currently implementing a procedure that will produce statistical garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the **forecast** package, with has the *BoxCox.lambda* function to handle
BoxCox transformations. The scale/re-scale is done automatically. Example:

```
 require(forecast)
 y <- ts(rnorm(120,0,3) + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:120)/12), frequency=12) + runif(120)
 lambda <- BoxCox.lambda(y) # should check if the transformation is necessary
 model <- auto.arima(y, lambda = lambda)
 plot(forecast(model))
```