# `scipy.stats.shapiro` show puzzling result

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, p-value

My system is python3.6, with numpy 1.16.2,scipy 1.2.1,matplotlib 3.0.3

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
import scipy.stats
a=numpy.arange(2,44,1)
print(scipy.stats.shapiro(a))
matplotlib.pyplot.hist(a)
```

Above script output as below:

```
(0.9560521245002747, 0.10655178874731064)
```

[image: Untitled2.png]

Obviously,`a` is not normal distributed,but `scipy.stats.shapiro(a)`'s `p-value` is `0.10655178874731064`
How can I accept this result?

What's the problem?

Comment: FYI: The [R](https://www.r-project.org/) function [`shapiro.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/shapiro.test.html) returns the same values (where "the same" means the first five significant digits agree).

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer to a question about testing for normality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781798/seeing-if-data-is-normally-distributed-in-r/7788452#7788452).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser,then, what method can be used to detect normal distribution?

Answer (score 0):

The results of `scipy.stats.shapiro` are unlikely to be incorrect here; as mentioned in the comments, the p-value is consistent with that produced by R's `shapiro.test`.

```
options(digits=16)
x = seq(2, 43)
shapiro.test(x)
# W = 0.95605246967015, p-value = 0.1065549026935
```

Compared to other normality tests, the Shapiro-Wilk test has good power with respect to *most* alternatives; however, it seems like you've found a case in which its power is not great. You have many other options:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
a = np.arange(2, 44, 1)
print(stats.normaltest(a))  # NormaltestResult(statistic=10.128923354263879, pvalue=0.006317310740453355)
print(stats.kurtosistest(a))  # KurtosistestResult(statistic=-3.0094922587552966, pvalue=0.0026168474735435423)
print(stats.jarque_bera(a))  # SignificanceResult(statistic=2.5257207700096096, pvalue=0.2828438260708052)
print(stats.skewtest(a))  # SkewtestResult(statistic=1.0353162312819313, pvalue=0.30052125208274305)
```

All of them except `skewtest` detect the departure from normality with a sufficiently large sample.

```py
a = np.arange(2, 44, 0.25)
print(stats.shapiro(a))  # ShapiroResult(statistic=0.9546093344688416, pvalue=2.9430553695419803e-05)
print(stats.normaltest(a))  # NormaltestResult(statistic=73.03250642958905, pvalue=1.3841805073962513e-16)
print(stats.kurtosistest(a))  # KurtosistestResult(statistic=-8.485467131605999, pvalue=2.1485385463319168e-17)
print(stats.jarque_bera(a))  # SignificanceResult(statistic=10.08142867266492, pvalue=0.006469125535965709)
print(stats.skewtest(a))  # SkewtestResult(statistic=1.014570839332235, pvalue=0.31031044559967047)
```

and the failure of `skewtest` is understandable, since it only attempts to detect whether the skewness is nonzero (and for your sample, it is not).